# How to update given environment variable values in JSON document

Tags: linux, environment-variables, json

I need to use the below JSON file as input and this file could contain multiple variable entries.
I need to search `var1` or `var2` in environment variables and replace the value in the below JSON.

```json
{
  "var1": "valueplaceholder",
  "var2": "valueplaceholder"
}
```

I tried the below command

```bash
cat input.json | sed "s/\"\([A-Z0-9_]*\)\":\s*\"\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)\"/\"\1\": \"$\1\"/g"
```

but it creates output like

```json
{
  "var1": "$var1",
  "var2": "$var2"
}
```

How can I get the value of variables? I.e. I need the value of `$var1` instead of text `$var1`.

Comment: You are re-inventing templating.   Don't re-invent the wheel, look for existing tools that do what you want and use them (if only because you'll run into all the problems and caveats and gotchas that the existing tool ran into and fixed years ago).  This looks relevant to `json` and templates: [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
$ cat file.json
{ "var1": "valueplaceholder", "var2": "valueplaceholder", "var3": "valueplaceholder" }
```

then, borrowing the `with_entries` structure from [How to swap key and value of an object using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40849180/4440445) and making use of jq's `$ENV` array:

```
$ export var1="foo" var2="bar"
$ jq 'with_entries( .value = $ENV[.key] )' file.json
{
  "var1": "foo",
  "var2": "bar",
  "var3": null
}
```

or if you want to set unmatched variables to the empty string or to retain the original values

```
$ jq 'with_entries( .value = ($ENV[.key] // "") )' file.json
{
  "var1": "foo",
  "var2": "bar",
  "var3": ""
}
```

or

```
$ jq 'with_entries( .value = ($ENV[.key] // .value) )' file.json
{
  "var1": "foo",
  "var2": "bar",
  "var3": "valueplaceholder"
}
```

or, if you want to *delete* the non-existing keys

```
$ jq 'with_entries( .value = ($ENV[.key] // empty) )' file.json
{
  "var1": "foo",
  "var2": "bar"
}
```